# Fastest way to check if a repository has changes?

Tags: git, bash, macos, terminal, zsh

I want to check if a git repository has changes.

I've been using this condition

```
if command git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null | grep -q .; then
  X
else
  Y
fi
```

but it's too slow.

Is there a faster method? Do I have to rely on the `git` command to do this or is there a super-fast method that bypasses using that command entirely?

Comment: If you want to know whether `git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null` outputs something: `if command git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null | read -n1; then echo "Repo has changes"; fi`. Will possibly be faster than your current test since we're getting rid of a subshell and an external command.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf why did you switch from `tail` to `read`?

Comment: `tail` is an external command and `read` is a builtin. Moreover, with `read -n1`, we only read at most one character (and not the whole stream). The same can be achieved with `grep -q .`, but `grep` is an external command, so it'll be slower than `read`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm getting `read: bad option: -1`

Comment: Don't use zsh `:)`. But if you really really want to use it, use `grep -q .` instead of `read -n1`... but it'll be slower.

Comment: I'd recommend putting your answer as an answer!

Comment: @minseong for `zsh` you can use `read -k1 -u0`. `-k1` is the equivalent of `-n1` and `-u0` is needed to tell `read` to read from the pipe instead from the terminal.

Comment: Do untracked files count as "changes"? If not, `--untracked=no` should help, performance-wise.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy I don't notice much of a difference, guess it helps minutely if at all. Have you time-tested it against w/o?

Comment: My repos are usually not big enough, but `--untracked=no` was introduced precisely to avoid the performance penalty of listing untracked files. Obviously, it depends on whether you have a lot of untracked files or not (I should have written "may help", not "should help" indeed).

Answer (score 2):

Git's own source code can give you a hint on a good solution: the [require_clean_work_tree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e31236f652ad9db221511eaf157ce0ef55585d6/git-sh-setup.sh#L210-L262) shell function does essentially what you want. Here is a shorter version (not looking at staged changes):

```
git_has_changes() {
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
}

if git_has_changes; then
    echo "has changes"
else
    echo "no change"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the `--short` option good for this sort of thing. It returns an empty string if nothing has changed:

```
test -n "$(git status --short)" && echo 'changes detected' || echo 'no change'
```

I don't know if there's any speed improvement.

Comment: The formatting is cleaner in answers. Have your bench marked this method?

Answer (score 0):

(edit: strip a GNUism, there's a reasonable posix-only test)

```
if (git diff-index --cached @; git diff-files) | grep -q .; then
        tracked changes in index or worktree
else
        index and tracked worktree content identical to checkout
fi
```

That lists paths with different content in HEAD and index, and paths with different content in index and worktree, without spending any time working out what those differences are.

If for some reason you want to shave every last millisecond off the response time you can use `stdbuf -oL git` to make git line-buffer its output, so the very first diff will immediately hit the sed and shut down the pipe; otherwise it might buffer up a few dozen detected diffs before printing them.

Comment: re stdbuf, just use `stdbuf -oL git` in place of `git`.  for the always-false part, I just tried it, make changes, it shows false, reset --hard, it shows true.  Typo perhaps?